# Ambari Failed to create principals while installing Kerberos

Tags: kerberos, ambari, kdc

I have installed MITKDC. I am enabling Kerberos using Existing MIT KDC From Ambari. While creating principals I am getting below error.

Failed to create principal, trinitylocal-071819@HUB.LOCAL - Failed to create a service principal for trinitylocal-071819@HUB.LOCAL
            STDOUT: Authenticating as principal admin/admin@HUB.LOCAL with existing credentials.

```
STDERR: WARNING: no policy specified for trinitylocal-071819@HUB.LOCAL; defaulting to no policy
        add_principal: Insufficient access to lock the database while creating "trinitylocal-071819@HUB.LOCAL".Administration credentials NOT DESTROYED.
```

I am able to create principals using kadmin.local.below commands also working. I am able to login to Kinit admin/admin also.

Klist command I have tried and I am able to log in. 
Below are my krb5.conf and kdc.conf.

Below is my krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
      renew_lifetime = 7d
      forwardable = true
      default_realm = HUB.LOCAL
      ticket_lifetime = 24h
      dns_lookup_realm = false
      dns_lookup_kdc = false
      default_ccache_name = /tmp/krb5cc_%{uid}
      #default_tgs_enctypes = aes des3-cbc-sha1 rc4 des-cbc-md5
      #default_tkt_enctypes = aes des3-cbc-sha1 rc4 des-cbc-md5

    [logging]
      default = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
      admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
      kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log

    [realms]
      HUB.LOCAL = {
        admin_server = HOSTNAME
        kdc = HOSTNAME
      }
```

Below is my kdc.conf

```
[kdcdefaults]
 kdc_ports = 750,88

[realms]
            EXAMPLE.COM = {
                database_name = /var/lib/krb5kdc/principal
                admin_keytab = FILE:/etc/krb5kdc/kadm5.keytab
                acl_file = /etc/krb5kdc/kadm5.acl
                key_stash_file = /etc/krb5kdc/stash
                kdc_ports = 750,88
                max_life = 10h 0m 0s
                max_renewable_life = 7d 0h 0m 0s
                master_key_type = des3-hmac-sha1
                supported_enctypes = aes256-cts:normal arcfour-hmac:normal des3-hmac-sha1:normal des-cbc-crc:normal des:normal des:v4 des:norealm des:onlyrealm des:afs3
                default_principal_flags = +preauth
            }
```

Comment: I am trying to add principal but I am getting Below error      add_principal: Insufficient access to lock the database while creating "test_user@HUB.LOCAL".

Comment: Below command is working             kadmin.local:  addprinc test
WARNING: no policy specified for test@HUB.LOCAL; defaulting to no policy
Enter a password for principal "test@HUB.LOCAL":
Re-enter password for principal "test@HUB.LOCAL":
Principal "test@HUB.LOCAL" created.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it is Installation Issue. I didn't give proper REALM